# Create new column and fill NaN in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe such as

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
NaN  A    3
B    NaN  78
C    C    668
D    D    56D
G    NaN  56
E    E    788
H    H    778
```

And I woule like to create a new `COL4` where I put `COL1` of `COL2` content if there is one `NaN`

exemple for the first row, there is `NaN` in COL1n then `COL4` will take the `COL2` value.

I should then get :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3  COL4
NaN  A    3     A
B    NaN  78    B
C    C    668   C
D    D    56D   D
G    NaN  56    G
E    E    788   E
H    H    778   H
```

thank you for your help and time

Comment: What should be result if COL1 and COL2 have a non-NaN values but they are different?

Comment: it cannot happen because I made a merge between COL1 and COL2 with ```how='outer'```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fillna`:

```
df["COL4"] = df["COL1"].fillna(df["COL2"])

print (df)

  COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
0  NaN    A    3    A
1    B  NaN   78    B
2    C    C  668    C
3    D    D  56D    D
4    G  NaN   56    G
5    E    E  788    E
6    H    H  778    H
```